# Cannot add items to the Registry on Windows 10 Access Denied

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, authentication

This looks like a trivial thing but I just can't get the Registry Editor to add items to my Registry. I found this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/262464/how-to-gain-full-permissions-to-edit-protected-registry-keys/. That didn't work for me because for the last step adding the user account (email) I don't seem to have a Microsoft Account available although I am logged in via Microsoft sign in.

I tried adding a new local user and take ownership of the registry (sub)tree I want to add but I cannot get passed the authentication process.

Funny thing is that if I look with 'Effective Access' it says I have 'Full control' but nah... doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Some registry keys are protected even from administrators. Which one are you trying to update?

Comment: Do you use any anti-virus/anti-malware softwares? If so, end them in taskmgr before editing registry, because some of them do lock certain registry keys and prevent writing to the keys.

Comment: Some keys are protected by trusted installer. You have to set you as owner of the key first and give you full writing permissions. Please kindly refer to this similar thread discussed before: [Regedit Permissions -"Access Denied" or "Error while deleting key" EVEN AS ADMIN!](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56fed319-a532-46a4-a384-fd795998c4a3/regedit-permissions-access-denied-or-error-while-deleting-key-even-as-admin?forum=w7itproinstall)

Comment: This question can be closed. There’s no need for an answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t work with the registry very often, but whenever I need to change ownership of a file in windows explorer, I don’t write my mail address, instead I write my full name, and this mostly works although the user is set up using a Microsoft account. You can try this, maybe it works.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. If I click 'Advanced' in the 'Select User or Group' dialogbox and then click 'Find Now' all the accounts are listed. Mine is not among them.